# Adding margin to the top and not affecting the height of container

Tags: css, layout, margin

Because of my navbar, I have to add margin whose height is same as the navbar's height. However, I get a scroll bar when I add margin because the height of body, html, and container is set to 100%. How do I add margin for the navbar, and not get the unnecessary scroll bar? And why doesn't `margin-bottom: -42px;` work?

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    z-index: 10;
}

.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 42px;
    // add margin from the nav bar
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML please?

Comment: navbar's position is fixed right now

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:42px;
    }` 
Absolute element remove out of dom and placed exactly at position specified by you

Comment: But if I set container to absolute, does the fluid property still persist?

Answer (score 0):

```
.container-fluid { overflow: hidden; }
```

This should hide the scrollbar